# Mobile Navigation hide/show one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

Hi I have navigation which shows and hides base on clicking the button. I know I could add a button in the hidden div which would close it. However, I want to have the same button show and hide the same div. Any thoughts? I tried reversing #hide and #show, but it then hides the original.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6xtd8/1/

```
    <div id="mobnavz"><a id="show">MENU</a>
</div> 
    <div class="target" style="display:none;" id="hide">
        <div id="mobnav">
         <ul>
                <li>Home Security</li>
                <li>Home Automation</li>
                <li>Business Security</li>
                <li>Business Automation</li>
            </ul>
</div>
</div>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         // This hides the Nav
         $("#hide").click(function () {
             $(".target").hide("slide", {
                 direction: "up"
             }, 500);
             $('#show').show();
             $('#hide').hide();
         });
         // This shows nav when button is clicked.
         $("#show").click(function () {
             $(".target").show("slide", {
                 direction: "up"
             }, 500);
             $('#show').hide();
             $('#hide').show();
         });
         // This animated the toggle.
         if ($('.target').is(':visible')) {}
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly.. you want to open and close a division upon clicking the same button. Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#show").click(function () {
         $("#hide").slideToggle(500);           
     });
     // This animated the toggle.
     if ($('.target').is(':visible')) {}
 });
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it does the trick.